# Enabling SSI on IIS

Tags: iis

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525940%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), I should be able to:

```
<!-- #include file = "..\myfile.htm" -->
```

Q: How do I enable SSI on IIS7?

Edit:
Oh, I see what my problem is: I'm on a VPS and they have the "Turn Windows Features on or off" disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

1) In the IIS Manager, go to "Web Service Extensions" and set server-side includes to "Allowed."

2) In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, right-click the "Web Sites" folder (for all sites) or right-click a specific Web site, and click "Properties."

3) In the "Documents" tab, make sure that index.shtml is included in the default content page list.

Comment: According to http://blogs.iis.net/nitashav/archive/2010/02/05/iis6-0-ui-vs-iis-7-x-ui-series-more-about-web-service-extensions.aspx, the Web Service Extensions was moved in IIS7, but I can't find a server-side include menu item.

Comment: It looks to be in the "Modules" area in IIS7.