# Include another HTML file in a HTML file Single Page Application

Tags: html, knockout.js, durandal, single-page-application

I have small requirement that i want to include productresults.html file in productsearch.html in durandal(Single Page Application). Can any one help me on this and i have tried the following ways also.

```
<link rel="components" href="productResults.html">
<!--#include virtual="productSearch.html" -->
```

Thanks,
shiva

Comment: What you're trying to do is a [Server side include](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html).  Your web server must be configured to support it - it sounds like maybe your server isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support and information.

Finally the code snippts works fine for me in SPA.

```
<!--ko compose: {view: 'nav'} -->
<!--/ko-->
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution using jQuery:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("productResults.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to do is a [Server side include](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html).

Your web server must be configured to support it - it sounds like maybe your server isn't?

It's also possible your web server might require the file to have a special suffix, e.g. "productSearch.shtml".

You can look here for more details:

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612391/enabling-ssi-on-iis
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2010/12/28/iis-notes-on-server-side-includes-ssi-syntax-kb-203064-revisited.aspx
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html