# #include in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, include

Can we have `#include` in `ASP.NET aspx` source code so that part of the `HTML` code can be moved to different `.aspx` page & called when necessary in the Parent.aspx page. I gone through the URL http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include but when I tried with `#include` Visual Studio 2012, intellisense didn't recogninzed it. So I'm not sure whether it is possible. Please guide.

Edit: I found another post [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file) regarding `#include`. Here they have mentioned about `HTML`. Can we follow same with `ASP.NET`?

I apologize if you feel this is a basic or lame question!

Comment: You probably want to be using User Controls for this functionality - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217601/when-do-you-need-ascx-files-and-how-would-you-use-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include html files like below

```
<!-- #include file = "..\myfile.htm" -->
```

Then you need to enable it in IIS.

Here is a [link](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/serversideinclude) for the same

Some other links which may help you

1. http://tech.mikeal.com/blog1.php/server-side-includes-for-html-in-iis7
2. [Enabling SSI on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612391/enabling-ssi-on-iis)